# Trying to use AWK to calculate Memory Used %

Tags: memory, awk

I'm trying to use **AWK** to calculate the **Used Memory** `% from vmstat -s`. Below is the command which I have tried

```
vmstat -s | awk 'NR==1 {total=$0}; NR==2 {used=$0}; END {print usedpct=used/total*100}'
```

But I don't seems to be able to get the output I want.

Any advise is appreciated.
Thank you.

Comment: [edit] your question to include concise, testable sample input (the output from `vmstat`) and expected output so we can help you. Just posting a script and saying "this doesn't do what I want" only goes so far and is highly crystal-ball-dependent!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are looking for this:

```
vmstat -s|awk 'NR==1{t=$1}NR==2{printf "usedpct=%.2f\n", 100*$1/t;exit}'
```

Answer (score 1):

Another ***awk*** approach:

```
vmstat -s | awk 'NR>2{exit}{a[NR]=$1}END{print a[2]/a[1]*100}'
```

---

`NR>2{exit}` - considering only the first 2 lines